# Add an invisible button to change screens in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm creating a game where I need to move between screens when I click on a specific place on my screen. I have created the QMainWindow Class but am having trouble with how to create the invisible button to change screens.

I added the code below any help is much apreciated. :)

```
import sys
import random

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from HomeScreenScene import *

class HomeScreen(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Puffle Pets")

        self.home_screen_view = QGraphicsView()
        self.home_screen_view.setScene(HomeScreenScene())
        self.home_screen_view.setFixedHeight(626)
        self.home_screen_view.setFixedWidth(628)
        self.home_screen_view.setSceneRect(0,0,626,628)
        self.home_screen_view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(1)
        self.home_screen_view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(1)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.home_screen_view)
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

def main():
    puffle_pets = QApplication(sys.argv)
    home_screen = HomeScreen()
    home_screen.show()
    home_screen.raise_()
    puffle_pets.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an invisible button you can set **style sheet** and make it's background color transparent.

For Example

```
btn = QPushButton(self)
btn.setGeometry(10,10,100,50)
btn.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;border:0;")
```

Hope it Helps :)